How to git exclude source files on the webserver but keep it on all other repos updating all past commits
I looked in many answers but I could make it work.
I am working with Adobe Animate games, so the source files are big .FLA files, I noticed that if I could ignore these files (more than 600) on our server we could save almost half of the space there.
So I put the *.fla and *.ai files inside the exclude on the server, but I believe it just working for new files, as this is a one year project all the files that already have referency will stay there. If I try to exclude them they will be excluded on Dev repos as well.
Is there a way of remove the actual reference?
Erase all the files from the server but keep them on Dev's repos?
Thank you!
All the extensios are already inside .git/info/exclude on the server
After that I exclude the files there, them the server ask me to commit, and all the files are erased, so I revert on my local, and when I pull into the server the files are back there.

Not familiar with FLA. What do you expect to happen when a new developer joins your team? How would they get the files?

Hi Loki, Fla is just a source file from adobe Animate(Flash). All devs will have access to this file, I just don't need it on the webserver so I would like to ignore it there.

Yes, but how will your devs get access to the file if you make it unavailable on the server?

The main idea is that the file is on git, we will download from there and upload there, we just don't need the file on the web server as no one is using it there.

Okay. I was assuming you were talking about a central repository server where your devs push their changes to. Please edit your question to describe your workflow with that web server. How does it get files? Is it doing a git pull -f, or another method of syncing the files (e.g. rsync, ftp or a simple copy)?
